# Xcode might display multiple iOS devices if you owned multiple iOS SDKs. I'm trying to know the distinction clearly about them

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

[image]

Please look at that, I can't understand the difference between those iPod devices. They seem  like such same things. If I select iOS 6.0 as iOS SDK, and select 4.3 as deployment target,  it will show a few same devices in the scheme. Really make me confused. 
Can you help me solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ran into this myself, I ended up naming the devices "iPhone 3GS", "iPhone 4", etc.

Comment: Actually, That's only one iPod Touch device. If I named it as you said that, it would show five devices named iPhone 4, iPhone 4, iPhone 4... .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going into the Xcode organizer and look at the devices along the left

Comment: There is also only one iOS version in Organizer. I think the five devices in scheme is prepared for compiling by different iOS SDK.

Comment: Try this going to this and removing anything below what your lowest requirement is:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/

Comment: Got it. I deleted all the iOS SDKs except iOS SDK 6.0, then there was only one device in the scheme. Thanks a lot.